# Sorting a list of fund names alphabetically within a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make the fund names in the following component alphabetically sortable...So value1 = fund1, value2 = fund2, etc should render in an alphabetical order. At the moment the order is miscellaneous.

Can someone suggest how I can change the following code to achieve this?

Thanks!

```
'use strict'

import watchlistProxy from 'common/watchlist-proxy'

export default function (groups, propName, isAscending) {
  if (!groups.length) {
    return
  }

  const sortBaseValue = isAscending ? 1 : -1

  const sortHandler = propName === 'favourite' ? (fund1, fund2) => {
    const value1 = watchlistProxy.hasFund(fund1.isin)
    const value2 = watchlistProxy.hasFund(fund2.isin)
    return value1 === value2 ? 0 : value1 ? -sortBaseValue : sortBaseValue
  } : (fund1, fund2) => {
    const value1 = fund1.sortingValues[propName]
    const value2 = fund2.sortingValues[propName]
    if (value1 === value2) {
      return 0
    }
    return value1 < value2 ? -sortBaseValue : sortBaseValue
  }

  groups.forEach(group => {
    group.funds.sort(sortHandler)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not clear to  me. But since you want to sort by name you can take this skeleton as source.

```
libraryItems
     .sort(
        (a, b) => {
            return a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1;
        }
    )
```

This will simply sort your object array by object's property name in ascending order or alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the order was being thrown out due to a case issue so I changed this line:

```
return value1 < value2 ? -sortBaseValue : sortBaseValue
```

to this:

```
return value1.toLowerCase() < value2.toLowerCase() ? -sortBaseValue : sortBaseValue
```

Seems so obvious now!